# Using implication operator for different address ranges

Tags: system-verilog

I am wondering how implication operator can be used if I want to choose between different address ranges.   I am using `if/else` condition, but it seems constraint solver is not accepting any solution for this.

```
  constraint ctCopy { mode == C_CMD -> if      (addr_range == "DST_SRAM") {dstAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                                          else if (addr_range == "DST_AXI")  {dstAddr inside {['h30000:'h3FFFF]}; }
                                          else if (addr_range == "DST_AHB")  {dstAddr inside {[20000:'h2FFFF]}; }
                                          else                               {dstAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                      mode == C_CMD -> if      (addr_range == "SRC_SRAM") {srcAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                                          else if (addr_range == "SRC_AXI")  {srcAddr inside {[0:'h30000]}; }
                                          else                               {srcAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                      mode == C_CMD -> cSize inside {[2:10]} ;
                      }
```

I am trying to use `with` constraint, but solver does not accept.  Here is the snippet:

```
  Trn0.randomize() with { mode == C_CMD; addr_range == "DST_AHB";};
```

small example to reproduce is as below

```
class top;
  rand logic [3:0] mode;
  rand logic [16:0] dstAddr;
  rand logic [16:0] srcAddr;
  string addr_range;
  rand logic [4:0] copySize;

  constraint ctCopy { mode == 1 -> if      (addr_range == "DST_SRAM") {dstAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                                       else if (addr_range == "DST_AXI")  {dstAddr inside {['h30000:'h3FFFF]}; }
                                       else if (addr_range == "DST_AHB")  {dstAddr inside {[20000:'h2FFFF]}; }
                                       else                               {dstAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                      mode == 1 -> if      (addr_range == "SRC_SRAM") {srcAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                                       else if (addr_range == "SRC_AXI")  {srcAddr inside {[0:'h30000]}; }
                                       else                               {srcAddr inside {[0:'hFFFF]}; }
                      mode == 1 -> copySize inside {[2:10]} ;
                      }
  
endclass

module tb;
  initial begin
    top tb = new;
    tb.randomize() with { mode == 1; addr_range == "DST_AHB";};
    $display("dstAddr=%0d,srcAddr=%0d",tb.dstAddr,tb.srcAddr);
  end
endmodule
```

Self contained example at:

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/rjZy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addr_range` is of type `string`, which means it can not be a `rand` variable.  One way to fix your problem is to set `addr_range` before you call `randomize`:

```
module tb;
  initial begin
    top tb = new;
    tb.addr_range = "DST_AHB";
    tb.randomize() with { mode == 1; };
    $display("dstAddr=%0d,srcAddr=%0d",tb.dstAddr,tb.srcAddr);
  end
endmodule
```

Another way is to use enums instead of strings if you want `addr_range` to be random.

---

When you run with Cadence on edaplayground, it generates warning messages about some of the values in your constraint being out of range.  For example, you declared `dstAddr` as a 17-bit value, but `'h3FFFF` requires at least 18 bits.  You should fix your values.